# How to make SVG pattern not responsive?

Tags: html, svg

I have the following SVG. The size depends where it displays.

I would like the pattern to stay at a defined size regardless of how big/small the circle is.

Is this possible?

Thanks :)

```html
<svg id="bg-circle" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 100 100" style="top: -219px; left: 0px; width: 3805px;">
        <defs>
            <pattern id="a" x="0.5" y="0.5" width="1" height="1" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" viewBox="0 0 28 28">
                <rect width="28" height="28" style="fill:#002a3a"></rect>
                <circle cx="21" cy="28" r="4" style="fill:#f7f7f6;opacity:0.03"></circle>
                <circle cx="7" cy="28" r="4" style="fill:#f7f7f6;opacity:0.03"></circle>
                <circle cx="28" cy="14" r="4" style="fill:#f7f7f6;opacity:0.03"></circle>
                <circle cx="14" cy="14" r="4" style="fill:#f7f7f6;opacity:0.03"></circle>
                <circle cy="14" r="4" style="fill:#f7f7f6;opacity:0.03"></circle>
                <circle cx="21" r="4" style="fill:#f7f7f6;opacity:0.03"></circle>
                <circle cx="7" r="4" style="fill:#f7f7f6;opacity:0.03"></circle>
            </pattern>
        </defs>
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" style="fill:url(#a);"></circle>
    </svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your SVG has a `viewBox`, so the SVG will scale to the size of its parent container. There is no way to make part of the SVG not scale.

If you want to change the size of the circle whilst keeping the pattern the same size, then change the size of the circle, not the whole SVG.

```css
svg {
  width: 40%;
}
```

```html
<svg id="bg-circle" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
        <defs>
            <pattern id="a" x="0.5" y="0.5" width="1" height="1" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" viewBox="0 0 28 28">
                <rect width="28" height="28" style="fill:#002a3a"></rect>
                <circle cx="21" cy="28" r="4" style="fill:#f7f7f6;opacity:0.3"></circle>
                <circle cx="7" cy="28" r="4" style="fill:#f7f7f6;opacity:0.3"></circle>
                <circle cx="28" cy="14" r="4" style="fill:#f7f7f6;opacity:0.3"></circle>
                <circle cx="14" cy="14" r="4" style="fill:#f7f7f6;opacity:0.3"></circle>
                <circle cy="14" r="4" style="fill:#f7f7f6;opacity:0.3"></circle>
                <circle cx="21" r="4" style="fill:#f7f7f6;opacity:0.3"></circle>
                <circle cx="7" r="4" style="fill:#f7f7f6;opacity:0.3"></circle>
            </pattern>
        </defs>
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" style="fill:url(#a);"></circle>
</svg>


<svg id="bg-circle2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
        <defs>
            <pattern id="a" x="0.5" y="0.5" width="1" height="1" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" viewBox="0 0 28 28">
                <rect width="28" height="28" style="fill:#002a3a"></rect>
                <circle cx="21" cy="28" r="4" style="fill:#f7f7f6;opacity:0.3"></circle>
                <circle cx="7" cy="28" r="4" style="fill:#f7f7f6;opacity:0.3"></circle>
                <circle cx="28" cy="14" r="4" style="fill:#f7f7f6;opacity:0.3"></circle>
                <circle cx="14" cy="14" r="4" style="fill:#f7f7f6;opacity:0.3"></circle>
                <circle cy="14" r="4" style="fill:#f7f7f6;opacity:0.3"></circle>
                <circle cx="21" r="4" style="fill:#f7f7f6;opacity:0.3"></circle>
                <circle cx="7" r="4" style="fill:#f7f7f6;opacity:0.3"></circle>
            </pattern>
        </defs>
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="25" style="fill:url(#a);"></circle>
</svg>
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this.It is 100% responsive. Hope you will find your solution.

```css
.svg-container { 
 display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 padding-bottom: 100%; 
 vertical-align: middle; 
 overflow: hidden; 
}
.svg-content { 
 display: inline-block;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
}
```

```html
 <div class="svg-container" id="bg-circle">
  <svg version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 500 500" 
preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" class="svg-content">
  <defs>
        <pattern id="a" x="0.5" y="0.5" width="1" height="1" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" viewBox="0 0 28 28">
            <rect width="28" height="28" style="fill:#002a3a"></rect>
            <circle cx="21" cy="28" r="4" style="fill:#f7f7f6;opacity:0.03"></circle>
            <circle cx="7" cy="28" r="4" style="fill:#f7f7f6;opacity:0.03"></circle>
            <circle cx="28" cy="14" r="4" style="fill:#f7f7f6;opacity:0.03"></circle>
            <circle cx="14" cy="14" r="4" style="fill:#f7f7f6;opacity:0.03"></circle>
            <circle cy="14" r="4" style="fill:#f7f7f6;opacity:0.03"></circle>
            <circle cx="21" r="4" style="fill:#f7f7f6;opacity:0.03"></circle>
            <circle cx="7" r="4" style="fill:#f7f7f6;opacity:0.03"></circle>
        </pattern>
    </defs>
    <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="100" style="fill:url(#a);"></circle>
  </svg>
</div>
```